# mlflow log model failed

Tags: tensorflow, mlflow

I tried to log my keras model with mlflow.tensorflow.log_model but got NoCredential error.
Is there anyway to solve it?

My tracking server is host in kubernetes cluster. The parameters and metrics are logged successfully besides artifacts. I want to log and register my model with tracking API. At first the log_model API returns traceback that "no module named boto3". then I installed boto3 with pip. now it returns new traceback.

I host tracking server on kubernetes cluster not AWS. Why mlflow.tensorflow.log_model will use boto3? Is there anyway to change it?

```
tracking_url = "https://......"
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_url)
mlflow.set_experiment('test_mlflow')

def create_classifier():
    classifier = tf.keras.Sequential()
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 12))
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss, metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier

classifier = create_classifier()


history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs,verbose = 1)

test_score, test_acc = classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size)

tf.keras.models.save_model(classifier, model_save_path)

run_name = "sample-ann-run3"
with mlflow.start_run(run_name=run_name):
    mlflow.log_param("batch_size", batch_size)
    mlflow.log_param("learning_rate", learning_rate)
    mlflow.log_param("epochs", epochs)
    mlflow.log_metric("loss", test_score)
    mlflow.log_metric("accuracy", test_acc)

    mlflow.tensorflow.log_model(model=classifier, registered_model_name="sample-ann-1", artifact_path=model_save_path)
```

the mlflow.tensorflow.log_model returned following traceback:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I found the client side needs to adding AWS access information as environment variables on the python file that run machine learning code and register model with mlflow.

os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = "<access_id>"

os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = "<access_secret>"

os.environ["MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL"] =